# Create a sample depending on another Variable

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

My goal is to create a data frame of 3 Variables (gender, Age and duration of employment) with the sample function. Here ist what i wrote already:

```
x <- data.frame(Geschlecht = sample(c("m","w"),10,replace=TRUE), Alter = sample(18:68,10,replace=TRUE), Dauer = sample(1:12,10,replace=TRUE))
```

My problem: The Duration should be bounded by the age of an employe. For example: When an employe is 20 the duration of employment should - obvious - not be longer than 2 years. How can i solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in `base R`

```
# Create a flag with your parameters
x$flag <- ifelse(x$Alter - x$Dauer < 18, TRUE, FALSE)

# If you want to filter out any results
x <- subset(x, flag == FALSE)

# Delete flag variable 
x$flag <- NULL
```

Here's a simpler solution using `dplyr`, assuming you want to filter out any invalid results.

```
library(dplyr)

 x <- x %>%
   filter(Alter - Dauer >= 18)
```

Result:

```
  Geschlecht Alter Dauer
1           w    23     3
2           w    62     2
3           m    61    10
4           m    45     9
6           w    56     3
7           m    64    10
8           w    25     1
9           m    60     5
10          w    63    11
```

Comment: In the `dplyr` answer, `x %>% filter(Alter - Dauer >= 18)` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can also do this without creating a column

```
subset(x, Alter - Dauer >= 18)
```